# Error while adding shared pointer to the vector

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

#### abstract base class:

```
#ifndef BUILDINGORG_H
#define BUILDINGORG_H
#include <iostream>
#include <memory> 
#include <vector>

class BuildingOrg
{

public:
   BuildingOrg(int _id);
   virtual int addBuildingComponent(std::shared_ptr<BuildingOrg> buildingOrg,
                                    std::string _type) const;
   virtual void removeBuildingComponent(std::shared_ptr<BuildingOrg> buildingOrg);
   virtual void getInfo()=0;
private:
   int id;
   std::string type;
};

#endif // BUILDINGORG_H
```

#### concrete subclass:

```
#ifndef BUILDINGCOMPONENT_H
#define BUILDINGCOMPONENT_H
#include "buildingorg.h"

class BuildingComponent : public BuildingOrg
{
public:
    BuildingComponent(int _id);
    int addBuildingComponent(std::shared_ptr<BuildingOrg> _buildingOrg,
                             std::string _type) const override;
    void removeBuildingComponent(std::shared_ptr<BuildingOrg> buildingOrg)
                                                        override;
    void getInfo() override;
private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<BuildingOrg>> building_Org;
};

#endif // BUILDINGCOMPONENT_H
```

#### Implementation of subclass:

```
#include "buildingcomponent.h"

BuildingComponent::BuildingComponent(int _id):
BuildingOrg(_id)
{
}

int BuildingComponent::addBuildingComponent(std::shared_ptr<BuildingOrg> _buildingOrg, std::string _type) const
{
    building_Org.push_back(_buildingOrg);// I am having error here
    return 1;
}

void BuildingComponent::removeBuildingComponent(std::shared_ptr<BuildingOrg> buildingOrg)
{

}

void BuildingComponent::getInfo()
{

}
```

When I try to put shared pointer in my Vector I get this nasty error;
I really don't know why I am getting the error:

> ```
> cpp:10: error: passing 'const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<BuildingOrg> >' as 'this' argument of 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = std::shared_ptr<BuildingOrg>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<BuildingOrg> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::shared_ptr<BuildingOrg>]' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
>         building_Org.push_back(_buildingOrg);
> ```

I don’t understand what is it saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `addBuildingComponent()` is a `const` method.  within its scope, `*this` is `const`, and so `this->building_Org` is `const`.
2. `std::vector::push_back()` is a non-`const` method.  So it can't be called in a context where the vector is `const`.

Answer (score 4):

The `const` in `int addBuildingComponent(std::shared_ptr<BuildingOrg> _buildingOrg, std::string _type) const override;` is a promise that `addBuildingComponent` will not change `BuildingComponent`. However, it tries to modify the member variable `building_Org` with the `push_back()`...

Removing the `const` from `addBuildingComponent()` should fix the error.

The `discards qualifiers` part of the error message refers to the conflict with the `const` qualifier of the member function.

C++ template related error messages can be notoriously difficult to parse at first, but it does get easier with practice :-)

Comment: To OP: the function needs to be made non-`const` in the base class also.

Answer (score 1):

You defined BuildingComponent::addBuildingComponent method as const (i.e. that it won't change member varialbles), but you are adding passed in value to a member list (i.e. changing the member variable).